# HQL/JPQL query with nested query and UUID array field

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

I need help with a HQL/JPQL query in Java Spring Boot project with Hibernate and Postgresql database.

Main entities are **Student** and **Lesson** (extra fields and annotations are ommited for brevity).

**Student**

Persistent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lesson_id")
    private Lesson lesson;

}
```

DB table:

```
create table student
(
    id         uuid,
    lesson_id  uuid
);
```

**Lesson** can be a part of different **lesson cycles** which are stored in **uuid[]** filed in DB.

Persistent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lesson")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(
                name = "uuid-array",
                typeClass = UUIDArrayType.class
        )
})
public class Lesson {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Type(type = "uuid-array")
    @Column(
            name = "lesson_cycle_ids",
            columnDefinition = "uuid[]"
    )
    private List<UUID> lessonCycleIds;

}
```

DB table:

```
create table lesson
(
    id               uuid,
    name             varchar(1000),
    lesson_cycle_ids uuid[]
);
```

I need a method `List<Student> getStudents(UUID lessonCycleId)` which returns list of students, which are linked to lessons with supplied lessonCycleId.

Now I ended up with below method in JPA repository:

```
@Query("FROM Student s WHERE s.lesson IN (SELECT les FROM Lesson les WHERE :id MEMBER OF les.lessonCycleIds)")
    List<Student> getStudents(@Param("id") UUID lessonCycleId);
```

but it doesn`t work. I have the following error on app startup:

> Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List ... StudentJpaRepository.getStudents(java.util.UUID)!

So I need help to fix the query please.

Comment: Try this query, `select s from student s where s.lesson in (select les FROM Lesson les where les.lessonCycleId = :lessonCycleId)`

Comment: @VenkateshK it's lessonCycleIds (a list in entity and array in DB), not a single value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no luck with JPQL so in the end I decided to use native Postgresql query instead:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from student where lesson_id IN (select id from lesson where :id = ANY (lesson_cycle_ids))")
List<Student> getStudents(@NonNull @Param("id") UUID lessonCycleId);
```